# Load Images in a List from Database at Server

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-layout

Guys I am not having an appropriate way to load images in the list view of android application. I have to load images in list with there text from the database.
the database which I am using is MYSQL and PHP Server.

Kindly help me out.

This is my code.

Activity Class:

```
public class DisplayMagazine extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> magazinesList;
int year;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MAGAZINE = "magazines";
private static final String TAG_MAGAZINE_IMAGE="magazineImage";
private static final String TAG_MONTH = "month";
private static final String TAG_PATH = "path";
JSONArray magazines = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_magazine);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    year = i.getIntExtra("year", 0);
    magazinesList = new ArrayList<>();
    new LoadAllMagazines().execute();
    ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
                    textView.setClickable(true);
                    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    String text = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ textView.getText();
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
            }
        });
    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
class LoadAllMagazines extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayMagazine.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Magazines. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", String.valueOf(year)));
        //String url_all_magazines = "http://172.16.26.190/shifaspeaks/get_all_magazines.php";
        String url_all_magazines = "http://10.3.1.117/shifaspeaks/get_all_magazines.php";
        //String url_all_magazines = "http://192.168.1.4/shifaspeaks/get_all_magazines.php";
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_magazines, "GET", params);
        Log.d("All Magazines: ", json.toString());
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                magazines = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MAGAZINE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < magazines.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = magazines.getJSONObject(i);
                    String month = c.getString(TAG_MONTH);
                    String path = c.getString(TAG_PATH);
                    //String imageString=c.getString(TAG_MAGAZINE_IMAGE);
                    //byte[] image= Base64.decode(imageString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    //Bitmap decodedByte= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(TAG_MONTH, month);
                    map.put(TAG_PATH, path);
                    //map.put(TAG_MAGAZINE_IMAGE,decodedByte.toString());
                    magazinesList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        DisplayMagazine.this, magazinesList,
                        R.layout.list_item2, new String[] {TAG_MAGAZINE_IMAGE, TAG_MONTH,
                        TAG_PATH},
                        new int[] {R.id.magazineImage, R.id.month, R.id.path});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and its XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and its layout for list :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/month"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and the PHP Server Script:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306','root','');
mysql_select_db("shifaspeaks");
$response = array(); 
if(isset($_GET["year"])){
$year = $_GET["year"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT month, path, magazineImage FROM magazine where year='$year'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["magazines"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $magazine = array();
        $magazine["month"] = $row["month"];
        $magazine["path"] = $row["path"];
        //$magazine["magazineImage"]=$row["magazineImage"];
        array_push($response["magazines"], $magazine);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No magazines found";
    echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

Remember I have to load images from database to the list in android with its text. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Hi first you have to make custom adapter, you can google it for how to make custom adapter in android and then make a Item class that describes your MAGAZINE.
And for displaying Image you can use Piccaso [Piccasso Image Loading](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library simply to diplay image from server.

Step by Step

1. make Class for MAGAZINE
2. make list item layout (it contains image and name and path)
3. make custom adapter that uses list item as above layout and MAGAZINE class
4. In custom adapter's getView method use any image loading library to load image from server.

that's it. Enjoy....

Comment: Thanks Bro :) Can I do it same for gridview as well?

Comment: yaa why not. just change list view to grid view in your layout xml

Comment: @ALISajjadRizvi have you able to implement it successfully ?